# Expected number of stops by a bus on a route

Tags: probability, expectation

Consider a bus with m people going through a route of n stops, $\{S_1,...,S_n\}$. People get off at different stations uniformly at random, independently of anyone else in the bus.

What is the expected number of stops the bus stops at (stopping only if someone wants to get off)?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint:  use indicator variables for each stop.

Comment: Yes, i've been down that road. $X_i = 1$ if the bus stops, 0 o.w. But you need P(X_i = 1) and that depends on how many people are still remaining on the buss at stop i.. and I have no good idea on how this would be calculated..

Comment: No....the probability that the bus stops at $S_i$ is just $1-\left(\frac {n-1}n\right)^m$ (it's just the complement of the probability that everybody on the bus gets off at a different stop).

Comment: Are the $m$ people already on the bus before stop $S_1$? Does nobody get on at the stops??

Comment: Correct, nobody gets on, think of it as end of the night from the bar :D

Comment: @lulu Ah, I see, how stupid of me. Then the whole thing gets much easier! Got it, thanks a bunch! (linearity of expectation)

Comment: Yes, that's right.